# Finding $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{|x^2 - x|}}{x^2 - 1}$

Tags: limits

I want to calculate $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sqrt{|x^2 - x|}}{x^2 - 1}$ . I tried to compute limit when $x \to 1^{+}$ and $x \to 1^{-}$ but didn't get any result .

Please help .

Note : I think it doesn't have limit but I can't prove it .

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can write the two limit as:
$$l_1=
\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{|x^2 - x|}}{x^2 - 1}=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{(1-x)}}{-(1-x)(x+1)}=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{-\sqrt{(1-x)}(x+1)}=-\infty
$$
$$l_2=
\lim_{x \to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{|x^2 - x|}}{x^2 - 1}=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{(x-1)}}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{(x-1)}(x+1)}=+\infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|x^2-x|=|x|\cdot |x-1|$, and $x^2-1$ is $|x-1|$ times something.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand second part . Can you explain please ?

Comment: $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$.